# vqmod throws strpos() empty needle error

Tags: php, opencart, strpos, vqmod

vQmod throws the following error when parsing an XML file:

> `Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /home/public_html/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 455`

Here's the XML itself:

```
<operation>
    <search position="before">
        <?php echo $footer; ?>
    </search>
    <add><![CDATA[
        <?php phpinfo(); ?>
    ]]></add>
</operation>
```

XML file looks ok, all paths are correct.

Didn't find anything relevant on the internet so posting my solution here (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `<?php ?>` tags inside of the `search` node.

Those should be escaped with `<![CDATA[  ]]>`:

```
<operation>
    <search position="before"><![CDATA[
        <?php echo $footer; ?>
    ]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[
        <?php phpinfo(); ?>
    ]]></add>
</operation>
```

Hope this saves someone else several minutes of time.